# Google play alike app opensource

Tags: android, open-source, google-play

I am trying to make an android app store in other language I mean separate from Google Play. Is there any way to have an app like Google Play but customizable for my app store.

thank's in advance.

Comment: Your question is not about a programming issue. And is therefore of-topic.

Comment: what to do then any help please

Comment: The only answer to your question is: Start learning how to program in Android, and put together your own "App store". As far as I know their are know opensource "app store" projects.

Comment: thank's again for your guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is FDroid - which might be exactly what you want. https://f-droid.org/

Open source code for FDroid: https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient

Comment: thank's for you answer.